# PMF of Poisson processes

Tags: probability, poisson-process

if i have 2 intervals on the same PP

[15,25]
[16,36]

the 2 pmf are still independent ?

Comment: $\textbf{WHAT IS PMF?}$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mjw : "probablity mass function". Each discrete probability distribution  is characterized by one of these.

Comment: @mjw : And one can define "discrete probability distribution" as one that is fully characterized by a pmf. Many books say it is one for which the set of its possible values is finite or countably infinite, but I have long viewed that as a definition by non-essentials.

Comment: Overlapping how, exactly? There are two possibilities - either a partial overlap or one interval is a subset of the other.

Comment: @Math1000 : Both of the possibilities you mention are included in the case in which $X$ and $Y$ have expectations $\alpha+\beta$ and $\beta+\gamma,$ where $\beta$ is the expected number of arrivals in the overlap. The case of one of them being included in the other is the case in which either $\alpha=0$ or $\gamma=0.$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Thank you.  Well, what is a pmf if not a finite or countably infinite set of probabilities?

Comment: @mjw : For one thing, the pmf has a domain; it's not just the image of the function. But I would take the proposition that the set of points in the domain whose probability is positive is at most countably infinite to be a corollary of the definition rather than to be the definition itself.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Okay, I think I understand.  The point is that finite or infinite set of values is fine, but it is the domain where these probabilities are supported that is also just as important.

Comment: @mjw : Note that in this context what is said is that it's finite or COUNTABLY infinite. If it merely says "finite or infinite" then it doesn't say anything, since EVERY set is finite or infinite. Next, it's not just the set of probabilities and the domain; it's WHICH points in the domain are assigned which probabilities. And there's a somewhat subtler issue: even with discrete distributions, the set conventionally known as the "support" can be larger than the set of points with positive probability. For example, suppose $\Pr(X=1/n) = 1/2^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots\,.$ Then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: For example, suppose $\Pr(X=1/n) = 1/2^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots\,.$ Then $0$ is not one of the points assigned positive probability, but $0$ is a member of the support because every open interval about $0$ has positive probability. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy,  Very nice!  Thank you!  Where to read more about this:   real analysis?  measure theory?

Comment: @mjw : Look at measure-theoretic approaches to probability.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Will do!  Billingsley, Dudley, $\cdots$.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$
(X,Y) = (U+V,V+W)
$$
where $V$ is the count in the overlap, and $U,V,W$ are independent and Poisson-distributed.

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{z\,=\,0}^{\min\{\,x,\,y\,\}} \Pr(V=z)\Pr(U = x-z)\Pr(W=y-z) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{z\,=\,0}^{\min\{\,x,\,y\,\}} \frac{\beta^z e^{-\beta}}{z!} \cdot\frac{\alpha^{x-z} e^{-\alpha}}{(x-z)!} \cdot \frac{\gamma^{y-z} e^{-\gamma}}{(y-z)!}
\end{align}

In case $\gamma=0,$ this has a closed form:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(V=y\ \&\ U=x-y) = \frac{\gamma^y e^{-\gamma}}{y!} \cdot \frac{\alpha^{x-y} e^{-\alpha}}{(x-y)!}.
\end{align}

(And if $\beta=0$ then $X,Y$ are independent and the sum has only the one term in which $z=0.$)